# Appcache working in Safari but not Chrome Windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome, caching, web, application-cache

I have a webservice running locally (I also tried hosting it on Windows Server). Chrome debugger shows the appcache loading ok and `chrome://appcache-internals/` shows the appcache itself.

As my app is using websql the only alternative browser for testing/control purposes available to me was Safari for Windows. The appcache works with this.

When I kill the webservice and reload the page, I get the standard Chrome `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error message. Also, under the resources tab in the Chrome debugger, the websql database is gone and the appcache is also gone.

I put my manifest file through a [validator](http://manifest-validator.com/) and it had no problems there.

Does anyone know if there's anything in particular I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any links to test this out?

Comment: @Kinlan - unfortunately not. edit: I see you're Google staff. Can I pm you a link for testing?

Comment: sure. paulkinlan at google dot com

Comment: @paulkinlan - sent, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is working in Safari but not Chrome this is normally because you have disabled Caching in the DevTools Network panel.  If you go back in to DevTools > Network and then on the top row ensure you don't have "Disable Cache" Toggled.

[image: Click this button]

Comment: Thanks a million Paul, this was my problem.